# Standard practice for storage of old / unused lithium ion battery cells prior to disposal

Tags: lithium-ion, safety, battery-storage

Is there a standard practice for storage of loose lithium ion battery cells that will be disposed of eventually? (in the timeframe of up to 1 year)

Currently, prior to disposal,
I have been storing unused lithium ion battery cells by taping up both ends in electrical tape, and then putting them into ESD bags, then putting ESD bags into a sealable metal container with rubber lining for insulation, with the container on concrete flooring. All in a dry room-temperature environment away from sunlight, as suggested from [here](https://ehs.oregonstate.edu/sites/ehs.oregonstate.edu/files/pdf/si/lithium_fire_prevention_si093.pdf).

Even with all that, there is some concern still that all these measures aren't necessarily safe.

From [here](https://www.gard.no/web/articles?documentId=35150780), there's some indication that lithium ion batteries can continue to burn  without oxygen.
("*Li-ion battery fires can continue to burn without access to additional oxygen. They may also continue to generate high amounts of heat following fire-extinction and are at risk of re-ignition.*")

along with some concerns about the possible [self-ignition of batteries](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/30615/can-lithium-ion-batteries-explode-or-self-ignite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the batteries won't thermally run away, they can be stored under your bed, but the point is that they *may* run away, and storing flammables under your bed is a bad idea in general, and they remain flammable even if they can't run away from stored electrochemical energy. The electrolyte itself is flammable even if the lithium were to disappear.

Once a cell runs away and gets hot, keeping other cells near to it in a box only aggravates things. A steel box is not much help if the hot gases will build up pressure, erode the seals, and turn the box into a little stationary rocket engine. They have a tendency to set stuff on fire :)

Make sure the batteries are fully and safely discharged, down to 0V. They are not meant for reuse, they are meant for material extraction. Keeping wonky cells for potential reuse by others is a whole another kettle of fish you don't want to get into - it's more involved that just storing junk cells for future recycling (not reuse!).

Make a point of them staying at 0V by soldering or clipping a jumper across terminals. Insulating the terminals is rather counterproductive: you want them at 0V, nothing else. Insulation will let charged cells slip surreptitiously into the junk pile.

When discharged to 0V, thermal runaway is not a viable outcome anymore AFAIK, so that's a basic precaution to take.

At that point, a basic 1/8" plate steel box kept outside, away from dry/flammable vegetation, should do fine. Make a 1/4" hole in the bottom of the box, and put it on a small pile of sand, so that if anything decides to go off inside the box, the hot gas will go into the sand. It's probably overkill, but I can't imagine it can be made any more inert than that, other than by dumping said box into a large drum full of water. Then you will have the unenviable task of having a drum of potentially contaminated water to dispose, but if you can manage to let it evaporate, the dry residue is just basic household hazardous waste.

Comment: I forget where I read it (and I'm not remembering all the chemist-written details because they were writing about three or four kinds of lithium batteries), but I do remember that the text written for commercial corporations said ***not*** to store these energetic lithium batteries with shorts across their leads. They definitely DID say to discharge them, first. But they were pointed about not shorting them for long term storage before disposal. (Actually, they also said not to store them for long periods, at all, and to get rid of them sooner than later.)

Comment: @periblepsis Very interesting! It would be good to know why, and what battery kinds don't like that treatment. The important assumption I make is that with a 0V short, the batteries are supposed to be at the lowest electrochemical potential energy state. I hope I'm not wrong. They are still flammable, and must be stored like other slightly unstable flammable materials would be - thus a sturdy steel box unlikely to be burned through, and having it sit on a small pile of sand for both thermal isolation and suppression of combustion products leaving through the bottom-facing hole.

Comment: I just recall that the chemist was saying it was better to discharge them, but then leave them afterwards. The details escaped me, but it had something to do with a dead short screwing with the battery long term safety design goals, its construction, and its reactive chemicals. The chemist-designer said that it was better to just discharge them and then let them `relax` (my word.) Safer, he said. Also mentioned keeping them between 10C and 30C, I think, as optimal. There was something about humidity, too. But can't recall that part. I was just skimming. If I find the darned thing I'll post it.

Comment: I think "battery relaxation" is something that involves the battery voltages increasing after a discharge, due to its internal chemicals. // If it helps at all, I did end up discharging the cells across a 1-ohm power resistor and it drew about 4A (well below its rated maximum). Once there was little to no current draw remaining, I then disconnected the resistor and observed that after about an hour the battery cell "relaxed" to about 1V.